# Problem while inserting a record with Form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a newbei Question.i want to insert a record to DB. no error occured but record has been not saved successfuly .my model name is adverb and the name of one field is name.here is my code:

```
     <html>
    <body>
    <% form_tag new_word_url(@adverb), :method => :post do %>

      Name :  <%= text_field :adverbs,:name %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= submit_tag 'Create' %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
   </body>
   </html>
```

and in my route

```
 match '/words/new'=>'words#new'
```

and Controller:

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  def new

         @adverb=Adverb.new
  end
  def create

    @adverb=Adverb.create(params[:adverb])

    if   @adverb
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def index

        @adverb =Adverb.find(:all)
  end
  def edit

        @adverb =Adverb.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

thank you for your helps

Comment: The name of my controller is Words

Comment: hehe. not controller name, but controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Name :  <%= text_field :adverbs,:name %>
```

should be

```
Name :  <%= text_field :adverb,:name %>
```

AND

```
<% form_tag new_word_url(@adverb), :method => :post do %>
```

should be

```
<% form_tag adverbs_path, :method => :post do %>
```

and in your routes

```
resources :adverbs
```

Comment: Thank you flOOr.God save you :)